# How to load images with Ajax jQuery into a slider while others images are being uploaded at the same moment?

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, web-services, asp.net-web-api

Any idea of how load images into a slider with Ajax jQuery making several requests to my DB (I will use a Web API architecture in .NET and the requests will be made once every 2 minutes) avoiding showing the pictures which have been showed before? I would like to know any algorithm for load images and avoid repeating the showed pictures

Comment: so the images are stored as BLOBs in the datatabase?

Comment: @BryanDellinger No, they aren't. They are stored as string.. I mean, we stored the path in the server...